# How to pass arrays from NodeJS to a Python script?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, arrays, electron

I wanted to make an electron app that calls a python script in the background. Now I have the problem of passing an array of strings from javascript to python. I already read about a solution using a flask-server but is this a good way of doing this, or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `json` and use node.js to write to a file and let python read from the file

Python

```
import json
with open("data.json",'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    f.close()
print(data)
```